# Can we make importing filename in python a variable, if we want to import files from different directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have different python modules in different directories:
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    dir1/
        __init__.py
        file1.py
    dir2/
        __init__.py
        file2.py
    foo.py
    bar/
         __init__.py
         calling_function.py
```

```
module_dict = {key1:file1,key2:file2,key3:file3}

def call_common_func(arguments,module_dict):
    for keyin module_dict .values:
        #I am looking for help for below line.
        from module_dict[value] import common_function 
        common_function(arguments)
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: HI @BeChillerToo, i have simplified the example i have added. Can you take a look?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you have several init.py in dir1, dir2, etc?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple sub-directories.

Comment: Why? What is the application you're coding? Having several directories named `dir1`, `dir2`, etc smells like bad code to me.

Comment: @BeChillerToo  i don't think that is bad code. But that is not the question here. I am looking for help in below code if that is feasible:
        ```from module_dict[value] import common_function ```